# How to concatenate two Int value and store in String in Swift 3

Tags: swift3

I have a simple question. Below is my code in Swift 3

Input:-

```
let x: Int? = 2
let  L : Int? = 1                              
var stringValue = String(format: "%d %d",x!,L!)
print(stringValue)
```

I want output 21 in string.

Comment: Why are x and L optional?

Comment: maddy i am new in swift so i have done the  mistake...

Comment: why people gives (minus point) what is the issue??on question....i WANT OUTPUT LIKE THIS.and i have give the information what i did so what is wrong in it??///don't give minus point as my question is not wrong....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all convert int into String like

```
let x = 2  // no need for optional like `let x:Int?`
let l = 1
var stringValue = String(x) + String(l)  // "\(x)\(l)"
print(stringValue)  // 21
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use like below to get string output.

```
print("\(x)\(L)")
```

It will give you output 21.

Answer (score 1):

You can add the int description to produce desire result as

```
let x: Int? = 2
let  L : Int? = 1
var stringValue = x!.description + L!.description
print(stringValue)
```

output is 21